# Phpmyadmin connects to localhost but not Server

Tags: mysql, linux, apache, phpmyadmin

I'm using a Lamp stack. I've been trying for hours to reconnect my phpmyadmin to my mysql db to no avail. I've tried re configuring and reinstalling phpmyadmin but it refuses to connect. Weirdly it will connect with localhost/phpmyadmin just fine. I don't understand why it would work for weeks and all the sudden it stops.

This is the error message (yes it looks like code):

```
if (!is_null($route)) {
            return $route->bind($request);
        }
        $others = $this->checkForAlternateVerbs($request);
        if (count($others) > 0) {
            return $this->getOtherMethodsRoute($request, $others);
        }
        throw new NotFoundHttpException();
    }
    protected function checkForAlternateVerbs($request)
```

I tried reconfiguring the config.inc.php file etc. Nothing works.

Any ideas?

Comment: `and all the sudden it stops` ... Are you telling us that you _could_ connect to the remote DB for weeks and now it cannot?

Comment: oops the code I showed above is actually the error i'm getting. Yes I was saying that when I surf to mydomain/phpmyadmin I have no luck. @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: @DrewPierce yes, I was connecting to the remote server for weeks with no problem. The code above is actually the error message. Apache seems to be working fine. My data renders fine on the website when I use queries so MYSQL is fine. It's just PHPmyadmin and I've tried reinstalling it etc. No luck.

Comment: ok then my fault Stack. Dang I don't know whether the error message should be blue or yellow now :>

Comment: @DrewPierce no worries ha. I think this error message is not very informational anyway. I've tried everything from reinstall, to editing config files. It's weird. Any ideas where I can look next? Would uninstalling Apache make me lose my mysql data?

Comment: who knows about that, but certainly down your mysql and grab the whole data dir copied somewhere else first

Comment: @DrewPierce yup thats done. Ok I guess i'll just go for an apache reinstall. Thanks for the help. I'll post the result.

Comment: don't let me be the impetus for a re-install, but good luck